# Dataview Filteration Problem

Tags: .net, filter, dataview

Can some one help with with the following code please!!

```
if (DiaryOccasions != null && DiaryOccasions.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    DataTable dtFilteredOccasions = new DataTable();

    if (ddlMonths.SelectedItem.Value != string.Empty)
    {
        string[] selMonthYear = ddlMonths.SelectedItem.Value.Split('/');

        if(selMonthYear.Length > 0)
        {
            dtFilteredOccasions = new DataView(DiaryOccasions,
                string.Format("MONTH(OccasionDate) = {0} AND YEAR(OccasionDate) = {1}",
                    selMonthYear[0].ToString(), selMonthYear[1].ToString()), 
                string.Empty, DataViewRowState.CurrentRows).ToTable();
        }
    }

    rptrDates.DataSource = dtFilteredOccasions;
    rptrDates.DataBind();
}
```

when tried it throws the following error at runtime:

The expression contains undefined function call MONTH().

Please help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dataview Filters do not work that way. It's syntax is similar to sql, but that doesn't mean you are allowed to call sql functions in your filter.